# Execute javascript in a javascript-disabled webview android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm working with Android webview, i have disabled server js by the following code:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

But i wanna execute my javascript (to change background color, text color, etc)
Is there any way to do this without re-enable js?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You disabled javascript, but you want to use javascript?

Comment: You could manually re-enable it each time you want to change something via javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the javascript execution.
Thank @Waclock, it works :D.

Comment: @BangNguyen no problem :-)

Comment: @BangNguyen please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make only your javascript work, as a workaround, you could re-enable the website's javascript, run your javascript, and then disable it again. This will allow you to interact with the DOM for a short period of time, without letting the user make use of any of the website's javascript.